# rank $\begin{bmatrix}-a\sin(t)\\a\cos(t)\\\beta\end{bmatrix}=1$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

> Consider the following matrix $\begin{bmatrix}-a\sin(t)\\a\cos(t)\\\beta\end{bmatrix}$, in which $t$ is a variable and $\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ is a constant.
>   What is the rank of the matrix?

Looking at the matrix I would guess the rank to be two, since I believe that $-a\sin(t)$and $a\cos(t)$ are linearly independent. I cannot find constant that multiplies by the two vector components in which the sum delivered is zero. However on the context of the problem I am working, the matrix should have **rank $1$**

**Question:**

What is the rank of the given matrix? How can I compute it? Is it 1?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any fixed value $t$:

The matrix is a $1 \times 3$ matrix, hence its rank is at most 1. The rank is $1$ exactly when the matrix is nonzero. Hence:

- if $\beta \ne 0$, then the rank is one.
- a $a \ne 0$, then the rank is one, because $\sin t$ and $\cos t$ cannot both be zero.
- if $\beta = a = 0$, then the rank is zero.

As others have pointed out, your question is not very clearly posed, so this may be a correct answer to the question you asked, but not the answer to the question you *meant* to ask.

Comment: Thanks for the question. Now I can clarify my doubt. I thought that rank meant the maximum number of linear independent columns or rows. Since we have on this matrix three rows I thought the rank would be at most 2 if we were able make $\beta $ into zero. Please, explain me why is the rank 1? Is my definition of rank wrong?

Comment: There's a lovely theorem in linear algebra that says that the row rank (number of linearly independent rows) is the same as the column rank (number of linearly independent columns), for *any* matrix (and therefore either one is called the "rank" of the matrix). Since the column rank of your matrix is clearly at most 1 (there's only one column!), the row-rank is similarly at most one, and the rank is at most one.

Answer (score 2):

For n-by-1 matrix with no all zero entries rank is always 1.